# Integrate Pysmell in Kate, how hard will it be?

Tags: python, plugins, scripting, kde-plasma, kate

I want to make a plugin for kate, to support autocompletion of python using pysmell. I don't know where to start and how hard it will be.

As far as I know, kate supports scripting with javasccript, which is ok for me, but I can't find any good documentation on it and how far it can get, if it is possible to source pysmell tags.

If anyone has any idea or is interested in this, let me know!

There is already autocompletion support in Kate, only if I could source Pysmell tags. That would be cool.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but just to let you know, PyDev is a free plugin for Eclipse that provides auto completion.

Comment: I used Pydev for many years already , it become so much work when i just need to edit a few file . Also when project getting bigger and bigger, it uses so much memory and becomes harder to manage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to do this. I think that it will be implemented in January of 2012.
I have other plugins, it's posible that it help you

https://github.com/goinnn/Kate-plugins

Comment: thanks! thats very cool.let me know when you start doing i could help too.

Comment: Ok, send me a e-mail. And when I begin I send you a e-mail info

Comment: Now I have a first-prealpha version of autocomplete in kate https://github.com/goinnn/Kate-plugins